# Using SequenceEqual and then returning which elements don't match

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have two `List<string>` and I am using the `SequenceEqual` method to determine if they match.

I now have a need to get a `List<int>, string, IEnumerable,` whatever of the indexes of the elements that have failed.

Is there an easy way?

Thanks

Comment: don't simple loops match your fit?

Comment: What do you want 'the indexes of the elements that have failed' to mean? `SequenceEqual` returns a `bool` for "these sequences are identical in their elements". There are many different ways of *characterising* a difference - what do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
List<string> list1 = ...
List<string> list2 = ...

var differentIndices = list1.Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => item1 == item2)
                            .Select((match, index) => new { Match = match, Index = index })
                            .Where(a => !a.Match)
                            .Select(a => a.Index);
```

Note that if one of the lists is longer than the other, this will not consider the items beyond the length of the smaller list.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the `Zip` method.  Looks useful for things like this.  Is there a similar method that includes all items from both sequences?  Seems incomplete without it.

Comment: @Scott: So beyond the length of the smaller list, you want to include all the indices of the bigger list?

Comment: No, I'm just curious if there's a method that does the same as `Zip` but extends to the length of the larger sequence instead of the smaller sequence. It could pass in `default (T)` or something. But it doesn't sound like it already exists.

Comment: @Scott: No, there isn't in standard LINQ to Objects as of .NET 4. You could write one yourself, however.

Comment: It just seems really weird to me that`Zip` exists! It really seems like a specific, one-off solution. And the name Zip is nearly meaningless. It just doesn't fit with the rest of LINQ. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Scott: Any reason you say that? `Zip` is a term from functional- programming, I believe. And the truncation to the length of the shorter sequence is consistent with the operator's implementation in other languages, such as Python.

Comment: Well that makes more sense. I have no experience with Python or functional programming, so the term is unfamiliar. Other LINQ extension methods, however, come from more familiar realms, such as SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
var firstFiltered = firstList.Except(secondList);
var secondFiltered = secondList.Except(firstList);

var bothFiltered = firstFiltered.Concat(secondFiltered);
```

---

Note: I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the opposite of the "intersection".  The intersection is the items that exist in both lists ... and you want the items that *don't* exist in both lists.
Here's a easy one-liner to do that:

```
var items = first.Union(second).Except(first.Intersect(second));
```

Example:

```
var first = new[]{"A","B","C","D"};
var second = new[]{"C","D","E","F"};

var items = first.Union(second).Except(first.Intersect(second));
// Result: "A","B", "E","F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your lists are **list1** and **list2**

```
 IEnumerable<string> setDifferent =
          list1.Except(list2);
```

The above will give you all the elements in list1 that are not in list2

Comment: Thanks. Will that give me the strings or the indexes? Is it possible to just get the indexes?

Comment: It will give you the list of strings that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

use that.

```
var diff = l1.Except(l2);  
Array.ForEach(diff.ToArray(), r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lists can be different lengths, you could do something like this:

```
IList<string> first = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
IList<string> second = new List<string> { "A", "Z", "C", "D", "Y" };

IList<string> longer = first;
IList<string> shorter = second;

IEnumerable<int> differentIndices = longer.Select((s, i) => i > shorter.Count - 1 || !s.Equals(shorter[i]) ? i : -1).Where(n => n >= 0);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", differentIndices));
```

This is effectively a one-liner. The results for this example are `"1, 4, 5"`.

The key point is that the `Select` maps the matching indices to -1, and these are then filtered out by the `Where`.